# Cindyjs: underline command not working (tex environment)

Tags: javascript, tex, cindyjs

I just started working with cindyjs and the [documentation](https://cindyjs.org/ref/TeX_Rendering.html#over-and-underlining)  describes the possibility to underline certain text within the Tex-environment. My problem however is that everything described in "Over- and Underlining" is not working properly except the \overline{text}- and \vec{text}-command. (just formatting issues for \hat{} and \tilde{})

Did anyone have a similar issue, or is there something I am doing wrong. A workaround would be helpful as well.

(I am using the latest version of cindyjs)

**Minimal example:**

```
<div id="CSCanvas"></div>

<script id="csdraw" type="text/x-cindyscript">
drawtext(A,"$\overline{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(0,-1),"$\underline{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(0,-2),"$\overleftarrow{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(0,-3),"$\overrightarrow{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(1,0),"$\vec{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(2,0),"$\hat{n}$",size->20);
drawtext(A+(3,0),"$\tilde{n}$",size->20);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gslp = [
      { name: "A", type: "Free", pos: [0, 9], color: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], visible: false, labeled: true, size: 3.0 }, 
    ];
    CindyJS({
        scripts: "cs*",
        defaultAppearance: {
            dimDependent: 0.7,
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            lineSize: 1,
            pointSize: 5.0,
            textsize: 12.0
        },
        geometry: gslp,
        ports: [{
            id: "CSCanvas",
            width: 3 * 500,
            height: 1.5 * 500,
        }],
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance